# Firefox not accepting CORS cookie when domain has port number

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, cookies, cors

I have a weird problem, I have got CORS working without cookies, and am now adding cookie support as my webservice uses cookies as part of its authentication mechanism for certain routes.

Now originally when I set the xhr.withCredentials = true it would receive and accept the cookie, but then I realised that the cookie's domain was "localhost" and subsequent calls to the service would not send the cookie over. This is still a partial unknown as to why it wont send the cookie back over, but it is presumed that it is because the actual service resides upon "localhost:1893" not "localhost" like the domain says.

So... I changed the domain in the service to correctly reflect the port number, so it was then "localhost:1893". However when the CORS request happens now, it receives the cookie in the response (you can see it in the firebug response), however the cookie is gray and doesn't appear in the actual cookies section of firebug.

Could anyone shed any light on this?

- Using Firefox 5
- Using jquery 1.6.1
- XHR has withCredentials set correctly
- Server returns correct CORS headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although CORS allows cookies to be sent/received between the server (by setting withCredentials to true), the cross-domain restrictions on the cookie still apply.  For example, you can't access the cookie in JavaScript using document.cookie.  I imagine Firebug is following the same rules.

Comment: hmm, this is kinda the other half to the other question you answered of mine "Jquery Ajax CORS + HttpOnly Cookie", as the cookies are not being sent back over. So I was assuming it may not be a problem with sending the cookies back like mentioned in the other question, but a case of it not accepting the cookie in the first place... hmm thanks for your response though, you are quite knowledgeable in this area Monsur!